# How to create range x values with basic R

Tags: r

I have just begun using R and have gone through multiple books and sources and they get more and more complex yet I still am unable to find a solution to what I think should be quite a basic process.

I have data with 3 columns as shown: (I am really simplifying everything to try and get a really clear answer which can applied to multiple situations)

```
min     max     value
1       5         23
8       15        9
33      35        30
```

I would like to plot this data on a graph.
by this data I intend that every value between 1 and 5 for example on the x axis is equal to 23 on the y axis.

I have tried several things including assigning each column to vectors a , b , and c respectively.
generating the correct number of values with:

```
y <- rep( c, (a-b+1))
```

which works as expected

then the problem occurs with getting the appropriate x values, I tried:

```
x <- (a:b)
```

but because of the way R functions it only applies to the first variables.
Now I can make this work by manually typing everything in like:

```
x <- c(1:5, 8:15, 33:35)
```

but I really need an automated way to do this because I am working with huge datasets of this structure.

I have seen some other people seem to have similar issues, however the underlying principle always seem to be convoluted with vast datasets and entire codes in questions so I have been unable to get to a good solution to this problem.
If anyone with a little more experience could clear up this issue I would be hugely grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
# your data.frame
df<-data.frame(min=c(1,8,33),max=c(5,15,35),value=c(23,9,30))

x<-unlist(apply(df,1,function(x)x[1]:x[2]))
y<-unlist(apply(df,1,function(x)rep(x[3],x[2]-x[1]+1)))

plotdata<-data.frame(x=x,y=y)                                

plotdata

    x  y
1   1 23
2   2 23
3   3 23
4   4 23
5   5 23
6   8  9
7   9  9
8  10  9
9  11  9
10 12  9
11 13  9
12 14  9
13 15  9
14 33 30
15 34 30
16 35 30
```

Answer (score 2):

```
dat <- read.table(text=
 "min     max     value
  1       5         23
  8       15        9
 33      35        30",
 header=TRUE)
```

I'm still not quite sure what you mean, but maybe:

```
newdat <- with(dat,data.frame(x=c(min,max),y=rep(value,2)))
newdat <- plyr::arrange(newdat,x)
plot(y~x,type="s",data=newdat)
```

It's not clear what you want to do between 5 and 8, 15 and 33 ... another possibility is to plot each bit as a separate segment:

```
plot(max~value,data=dat,xlim=range(c(dat$min,dat$max)),
     type="n")
apply(dat,1,function(x) segments(x[1],x[3],x[2],x[3]))
```

Comment: And a `points` variation if you need each individual point plotted: `apply(dat,1, function(x) { xpts <- x[1]:x[2]; points(xpts,rep(x[3],length(xpts)))})`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
a <- c(c(1:5), c(8:15), c(33:35))
b <- c(rep(23,5), rep(9,8), rep(30,3))
plot(a,b, type="l")
```